# Can I upload a document from my local drive to facebook group using Facebook c# SDK?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, file-upload, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-group

I have read somewhere that I can only post the documents as Url to facebook group.. facebook does not allow direct uploading of file from local drive to facebook group..

Is that correct? Any Help on this? Is there any alternate way to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about the API, but manually it seems you can upload files to groups:
http://cauciu.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/how-to-upload-file-to-facebook-groups/

Comment: Thanks buddy. but I know I can do it manually. I only want it to be done using Facebook API.

Comment: You could try automating the browser, or check out how they're doing it in their Javascript (reverse engineer it), depending on how determined you are...